# minimizing non-convex function with Nelder-Mead

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, with the default method ('Neldear-Mead').
The function I try to minimize is not strictly convex. It stays at the same value on some significant areas.

The issue that I have is that the steps taken by the algorithm are too small. For example my starting point has a first coordinate `x0 = 0.2` . I know that the function will result in a different value only for a significant step, for example moving by 0.05. Unfortunately, I can see that the algorithm makes very small step (moving by around 0.000001). As a result, my function returns the same value, and the algorithm does not converge. Can I change that behaviour?

For convenience, here's the scipy code:

```
def _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args=(), callback=None,
                         xtol=1e-4, ftol=1e-4, maxiter=None, maxfev=None,
                         disp=False, return_all=False,
                         **unknown_options):
    """
    Minimization of scalar function of one or more variables using the
    Nelder-Mead algorithm.

    Options for the Nelder-Mead algorithm are:
        disp : bool
            Set to True to print convergence messages.
        xtol : float
            Relative error in solution `xopt` acceptable for convergence.
        ftol : float
            Relative error in ``fun(xopt)`` acceptable for convergence.
        maxiter : int
            Maximum number of iterations to perform.
        maxfev : int
            Maximum number of function evaluations to make.

    This function is called by the `minimize` function with
    `method=Nelder-Mead`. It is not supposed to be called directly.
    """
    _check_unknown_options(unknown_options)
    maxfun = maxfev
    retall = return_all

    fcalls, func = wrap_function(func, args)
    x0 = asfarray(x0).flatten()
    N = len(x0)
    rank = len(x0.shape)
    if not -1 < rank < 2:
        raise ValueError("Initial guess must be a scalar or rank-1 sequence.")
    if maxiter is None:
        maxiter = N * 200
    if maxfun is None:
        maxfun = N * 200

    rho = 1
    chi = 2
    psi = 0.5
    sigma = 0.5
    one2np1 = list(range(1, N + 1))

    if rank == 0:
        sim = numpy.zeros((N + 1,), dtype=x0.dtype)
    else:
        sim = numpy.zeros((N + 1, N), dtype=x0.dtype)
    fsim = numpy.zeros((N + 1,), float)
    sim[0] = x0
    if retall:
        allvecs = [sim[0]]
    fsim[0] = func(x0)
    nonzdelt = 0.05
    zdelt = 0.00025
    for k in range(0, N):
        y = numpy.array(x0, copy=True)
        if y[k] != 0:
            y[k] = (1 + nonzdelt)*y[k]
        else:
            y[k] = zdelt

        sim[k + 1] = y
        f = func(y)
        fsim[k + 1] = f

    ind = numpy.argsort(fsim)
    fsim = numpy.take(fsim, ind, 0)
    # sort so sim[0,:] has the lowest function value
    sim = numpy.take(sim, ind, 0)

    iterations = 1

    while (fcalls[0] < maxfun and iterations < maxiter):
        if (numpy.max(numpy.ravel(numpy.abs(sim[1:] - sim[0]))) <= xtol and
                numpy.max(numpy.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= ftol):
            break

        xbar = numpy.add.reduce(sim[:-1], 0) / N
        xr = (1 + rho) * xbar - rho * sim[-1]
        fxr = func(xr)
        doshrink = 0

        if fxr < fsim[0]:
            xe = (1 + rho * chi) * xbar - rho * chi * sim[-1]
            fxe = func(xe)

            if fxe < fxr:
                sim[-1] = xe
                fsim[-1] = fxe
            else:
                sim[-1] = xr
                fsim[-1] = fxr
        else:  # fsim[0] <= fxr
            if fxr < fsim[-2]:
                sim[-1] = xr
                fsim[-1] = fxr
            else:  # fxr >= fsim[-2]
                # Perform contraction
                if fxr < fsim[-1]:
                    xc = (1 + psi * rho) * xbar - psi * rho * sim[-1]
                    fxc = func(xc)

                    if fxc <= fxr:
                        sim[-1] = xc
                        fsim[-1] = fxc
                    else:
                        doshrink = 1
                else:
                    # Perform an inside contraction
                    xcc = (1 - psi) * xbar + psi * sim[-1]
                    fxcc = func(xcc)

                    if fxcc < fsim[-1]:
                        sim[-1] = xcc
                        fsim[-1] = fxcc
                    else:
                        doshrink = 1

                if doshrink:
                    for j in one2np1:
                        sim[j] = sim[0] + sigma * (sim[j] - sim[0])
                        fsim[j] = func(sim[j])

        ind = numpy.argsort(fsim)
        sim = numpy.take(sim, ind, 0)
        fsim = numpy.take(fsim, ind, 0)
        if callback is not None:
            callback(sim[0])
        iterations += 1
        if retall:
            allvecs.append(sim[0])

    x = sim[0]
    fval = numpy.min(fsim)
    warnflag = 0

    if fcalls[0] >= maxfun:
        warnflag = 1
        msg = _status_message['maxfev']
        if disp:
            print('Warning: ' + msg)
    elif iterations >= maxiter:
        warnflag = 2
        msg = _status_message['maxiter']
        if disp:
            print('Warning: ' + msg)
    else:
        msg = _status_message['success']
        if disp:
            print(msg)
            print("         Current function value: %f" % fval)
            print("         Iterations: %d" % iterations)
            print("         Function evaluations: %d" % fcalls[0])

    result = OptimizeResult(fun=fval, nit=iterations, nfev=fcalls[0],
                            status=warnflag, success=(warnflag == 0),
                            message=msg, x=x)
    if retall:
        result['allvecs'] = allvecs
    return result
```

Comment: From my experience with Nelder Mead, they work well with convex problems but are not suited for general purpose non-convex problems. Without knowing exactly the parameter space you are going to be using Nelder Mead, it will be difficult to say if shifting it by 0.05 will always ensure a solution.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have a suggestion for a non-convex function?

Comment: The function is for you to define. From your description, there is at least a region where there is a flat plateau. Are there local minimums too? The great thing about Nelder Mead is that it is very physical. You can literally think of it as water flowing down a physical landscape.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I definitely have my non-convex function, with several local minima (I am not worried about that, I will just inject several good starting points). I meant do you have a suggestion for a minimization algorithm?

Comment: There are two major approaches: deterministic and stochastic global optimization. Both of these areas contain a lot of very interesting ideas/heuristics. I am not an expert but if I have an global optimization problem, I would try to understand the general layout of the parameter space. Then pick how I wish to attack problem. It could be a hybrid approach where different techniques/algos are combined together.

Comment: For deterministic global optimization I found the DIRECT algorithm to work quite well for the problems I have been working on. You can check out a scipy.optimize like interface to it here: https://github.com/andim/scipydirect/

Answer (score 1):

I have used Nelder-Mead long time ago,but as I remember that you will find different local minima if you start from different starting points.You didn't give us your function,so we could only guess what should be best strategy for you.You should also read this

```html
http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~fuchang/res/ANMS.pdf
```

Then you can try pure Python implementation

```html
https://github.com/fchollet/nelder-mead/blob/master/nelder_mead.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am aware of having different local minima, and I take care of that. I'll go through your links.